# Is it possible to search questions in "AND" manner?

Tags: support, search, tag-search

On Stack Overflow when we are searching for some questions that are related with some specific tags, we are only able search in a 1st-tag **OR** 2nd-tag manner (example: *css* **OR** *html*), which displays questions tagged with *css* **OR** questions tagged with *html*.

Instead of that, how can I search questions in an **AND** matter, which means I wish to see the questions which are tagged with both *html* **AND** *css* tags?

Comment: sorry...which is again shown the questions in OR manner

Comment: i want to get all questions which are tagged with **both html and css** ,is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

'AND' is the default search behaviour - just type the terms after each other. Because they are in the top 40 tags, they are [automatically converted](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/) to tag searches.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css%20html

For 'OR', just put the word `or` between the tags, as mentioned in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching):

> #### OR operator
>
> To combine results from multiple tags, separate the tag names (enclosed in square brackets) with the word "or": `[widgets] or [geegaws]` returns questions tagged with *either* tag.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css%20or%20html